# Exponential stability under global diffeomorphism

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory

Consider a system of the form
\begin{equation}
\Sigma\colon\ \dot{x}=f(x),
\end{equation}
where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a sufficiently smooth function vanishing at the origin. Assume that $\Sigma$ has a *globally exponentially stable* equilibrium at $x=0$. Now apply a global coordinate transformation
\begin{equation}
z=T(x),
\end{equation}
where $T\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$, $T(0)=0$ is a global $\mathcal{C}^1$ diffeomorphism. Accordingly, we obtain the transformed system
\begin{equation}
\Sigma^\prime \colon\ \dot{z}=g(z):=\frac{\partial T(x)}{\partial x}f(x)\bigg|_{x=T^{-1}(z)}.
\end{equation}
**Question:** Is $\Sigma^\prime$ globally exponentially stable at $z=0$?

Comment: Clearly not, in general. You should be able to give counterexamples easily, I suggest that you take $n=1$ and think of $T(x)$ similar to $\log x$ for very large $x$.

Comment: Thanks @John B, could you please introduce some references that have discussed stability under coordinate transformation?

Comment: What would be the interest in making coordinate changes to study stability?

Comment: In a certain nonlinear control problem, I have two systems that are related to each other by a global $C^1$ diffeomorphism. For one of the systems (the $z$-dynamics), I have proved exponential stability. Now I was wondering that is it possible to infer the same result for the other system (the $x$-dynamics)?

Comment: It depends on what is your diffeomorphism, but as I noted above in general such a diffeomorphism does not preserve exponential stability, although it preserves stability and asymptotic stability (quantitative versus qualitative).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Moreover, let $x(t)$ and $y(t) = \Phi(x(t))$ be solutions of the systems
$$
\dot{x}=f(x,t), \quad x\in\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n,
$$
and 
$$
\dot{y}=h(y,t), \quad y\in\Phi(\Omega)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n,
$$
respectively (the second system is the transformed first system, $\quad y=\Phi(x)$ is a diffeomorphism); suppose that the solution $y(t)$ is
bounded and exponentially stable; finally, exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that a closed $\epsilon$-neighborhood of any point of $y(t)$ is a subset
of $\Phi(\Omega)$. Then the solution $x(t)$ is exponentially stable.

The proof of this fact can be found in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0012266107110043

**Update:**
The main idea of the (simplified, for an equilibrium point and for $\Omega=\Phi(\Omega)=\mathbb R^n$) proof is as follows. Let the zero solution of the system 
$$\tag{1}
\dot y= g(y),\quad g(0)=0
$$
be exponentially stable.  It means, by definition, that there exists
$\delta>0$ such that $\forall y_0 \in D_{\delta}=\{y:\; \|y\|< \delta\}$
the solution of the initial value problem 
$$
\dot y= g(y),\quad y(0)=y_0
$$
satisfies
$$\tag{2}
\|y(t)\|\le M e^{-\gamma (t-t_0)}\|y_0\|,
$$
where $M$ and $\gamma$ are some positive constants.

Let $\Phi(x)$ be a diffeomorphism, $\Phi(0)=0$.
Since $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism and, consequently, $\Phi^{-1}$ is also a diffeomorphism, they fulfill the Lipschitz property
$$\tag{3}
\|\Phi(x_1)-\Phi(x_2)\|\le L \|x_1-x_2\|
$$
for any $x_1,x_2\in \Phi^{-1}\left(D_{\delta}\right)$ and, respectively,
$$\tag{4}
\|\Phi^{-1}(y_1)-\Phi^{-1}(y_2)\|\le L' \|y_1-y_2\|
$$
for any $y_1,y_2\in D_{\delta}$, where $L$,$L'$ are some constants.

Now one can combine (2), (3) and (4) and obtain $\forall x_0 \in 
\Phi^{-1}\left(D_{\delta}\right)$, $y(t)=\Phi(x(t))$, $y_0=\Phi(x_0)$
$$\tag{5}
\|x(t)\|=\|x(t)-0\|=\| \Phi^{-1}\left(y(t)\right)-\Phi^{-1}(0) \|\le 
L' \|y(t)-0\|
$$
$$
\le L' M e^{-\gamma (t-t_0)}\|y_0\|= L' M e^{-\gamma (t-t_0)}\|\Phi(x_0)-\Phi(0)\|\le L' M L e^{-\gamma (t-t_0)}\|x_0\|
$$
Thus, the zero solution of the system in variables $x$ is exponentially stable.

As for the global exponential stability, well, (3) and (4) are not, in general, satisfied in $\mathbb R^n$ for an arbitrary diffeomorphism; but if the solutions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are contained in some compact sets (which is a common case for control theory problems), then one can determine the constants $L$ and $L'$ and establish (5).